# Regex to block BCC emails

Tags: regex

I am trying to block/hold all emails that are BCC'd to our domain with our domain also not appearing within the To or CC fields. I appreciate some legitimate emails may be sent this way but it is still what we are trying to do.

I have tried various other solutions but regex has been mentioned as maybe being the only way that I could achieve this.

I am not familiar with regex but below is what I have come up with.

```
.*^Bcc:[^\r\n]*\b[^\r\n]@domain\.co.uk\b[^\r\n]*\s$
```

The problem with the above is it seems to rely on the BCC field being present in the headers which it won't be.

I am really hoping that there will be a way that I can use regex to specify the domain not showing in the TO: or CC: fields and from their using it as a filter to to hold the email. I am trying to get my head around this but if there is any possibility of help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You would have to do this on your domain's email server, so it is a mail server configuration problem, so it's off-topic here. Maybe [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) would be the correct place to ask.

Comment: post a source data as example, please